# adding deleted file info to a single file [UNIX]

Tags: file, unix, linode

So I have the simple problem

> In order to restore files, the original directory and filename must be
> stored.
>
> Create a hidden file called ".restore.info".  Each line of
> this file should contain the name of a stored file, followed by a
> colon, followed by the original full path and filename.
>
> For example,
> if file f1 with inode 1234 were removed from the /home/usr1.name/
> directory and another file named f1 with inode 5432 were removed from
> the /home/usr1.name/testing directory then .restore.info would
> contain:
>
> f1_1234:/home/usr1.name/f1
>
> f1_5432:/home/usr1.name/testing/f1

any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Or rather, I understand the problem, but I don't understand how I could help to solve it. Where have you got up to, and what's the thing that you need to do that you're stuck on? What does your solution do so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls f* | parallel 'echo {}_`stat -c%i {}`:$PWD/{} >> .restore.info ;mv {} recycleBin/{}_`stat -c%i {}`'
```

hope this works +